# magento front end is not working

Tags: magento-1.4

the admin form is working well but problem with the front end

problem that

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 847199895

please help
regards
Ankush

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you are new to magento. But no worrys, you find the exact error.

Go to your magento installation folder. You will see a folder named "errors". In that folder rename the local.xml.sample file to local.xml.

Your frontend will display the errors instead of Error log record number: 847199895. Copy the error and let me know what it is. So that I can help you.

Comment: sorry but i seen your reply after installing it